# crontab failing to run a shell script that wgets a url at a specified interval

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, wget

I have the following command inside a shell script at /home/ubuntu/wget_my_url.sh

the conent of ping_my_url are as follows -

`wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.someurl.com/baseurl/`

There is no line break in the above file. 
I did chmod +x wget_my_url.sh

Inside my /etc/crontab I have the following - `*/1 * * * * /home/ubuntu/wget_my_url.sh`

There is a line break after the above line inside the crontab file.

When I run manually wget_my_url.sh, I get the desired result, but inside a cron tab, it does not run.

Please let me know, whats wrong with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Well the mistake was, I was writing the above script in /etc/cron and later, I moved it to crontab -e

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with the "desired result" ?

Your script just print choses on the screen (the standard out), but, the scripts on the crontab doesn't have a screen to print.

So, I think that it's running normally but you can't realize cause you don't see the script's output.

Instead of just print, why don't you print on a file making something like

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.someurl.com/baseurl/ > /home/ubuntu/OUT_FILE
```

?

Like that you'll be able to check if it works just checking if the file /home/ubuntu/OUT_FILE exists and you'll be able to use the script's output too.

Comment: The output from Cron jobs get sent by email to the owner. Maybe check that email isn't broken, though.